# Dell Inspiron 1470 stuck on blinking cursor after battery replacement

Tags: laptop, battery, dell-inspiron, laptop-repair

I recently replaced the battery in a Dell Inspiron 1470 and when I turn it on it shows the Dell logo then it goes to a black screen with a blinking underscore character in the top left. What’s happening and how do I make my laptop boot again?

Comment: Most laptops need certified OEM batteries to run properly. Dell, HP, and Lenovo all do this. Did you use a proper OEM Battery?

Comment: what do you mean by OEM? I just got one that was compatible with the laptop off of eBay.

Comment: OEM means Original Equipment Manufacturer.  As I posted, you need to ensure the battery you purchased on eBay is fully compatible. Some eBay sources are good (I use them) and some are dodgy (I do not use these)

Comment: Ah. I just checked the seller and they say it is "100% certified OEM". So clearly the battery is not the issue. What else could it be?

Comment: I suggest returning the battery.  Since that is all that changed prior to the error, battery does appear to be the issue.

Comment: No I don't think so because before I just had an error that said it wasn't recognizing the battery but now thats gone and replaced with the current issue. Sorry I guess I should have clarified that before.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this Dell article.

[Dell Battery replacement](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-ca/000175212/dell-laptop-battery-frequently-asked-questionsv)

> CAUTION: Using a third-party or non-Dell battery or an incompatible
> battery may increase the risk of fire or explosion. Replace the
> battery only with a compatible battery purchased from Dell that is
> designed to work with your Dell computer. Do not use a battery from
> other computers with your computer.

It may be that the battery replacement did not meet Dell laptop specs. So it may be necessary to use a proper OEM compatible battery.

You must replace your Dell Battery with a certified OEM replacement.

Dell (of course) sells proper batteries.

Dr Battery (see Amazon) also sells exact OEM replacements that work (I have done this with an older (10 years old) Lenovo X230 and that worked well.

The key is to use a proper certified OEM replacement.

Comment: This is not feasible advice, the laptop is ancient. Using third-party batteries in laptops is an established practice and poses no danger whatsoever given a compatible battery. // It also simply does not answer the question.

Comment: As long as the battery is OEM certified they will work. So my answer (use Dell or certified OEM ) is truly the best advice.  It I also accurate